# presto: how to combine 2 columns' values into one column

Tags: mysql, sql, presto

I am a beginner of SQL. I have a table like the following:

```
Id start_place  end_place
1   a            b
2   b            c 
3   d            e
4   a            e
```

desired output:

```
 place
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e
```

I want to find combine the distinct values and distinct values from start_place and end_place and combine them into a column (if there are duplicates, e.g., b are in both start and end place, show b only once).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union`:

```
select start_place
from t
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select end_place
from t;
```

Note that `union` removes duplicates.  Under most circumstances, you want `union all` so you don't incur the overhead of removing duplicates.  In this case, though, duplicate remove is what you really want.

Comment: Did UNION [DISTINCT] always behave this way (I mean even prior to 5.5)?

Comment: "UNION" is "UNION DISTINCT" per SQL spec. If you execute query in Presto or Trino, the UNION operation happens in the cluster, not within MySQL, so MySQL version doesn't matter.